# html5 application cache manifest file progress error

Tags: html, tomcat

in my web app i am using simple.manifest file for application cache. if i write as

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:

img/logo.png

FALLBACK:

/ offline.html

NETWORK:

*
```

it's working fine. but if i write as

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:

/img/logo.png

FALLBACK:

/ /offline.html

NETWORK:

*
```

it's not working. i am getting error resourse fetch failed(404) .
i am working in apche tomcat. i pute my apps as

apache/webapps/sconnolly/offline.html

apache/webapps/sconnolly/img/logo.png

apache/webapps/sconnolly/sample.manifest

what may be cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The leading slash refers to the root directory. Whereas if you omit the leading slash the url will be relative to the path you're in.

Therefore:

> img/logo.png will refer to apache/webapps/sconnolly/img/logo.png

Whereas

> /img/logo.pmg will most likely refer to apache/webapps/img/logo.png